# Why is my app viewport smaller on Heroku than it is on localhost?

Tags: html, css, heroku, size, production

It appears that the viewport is smaller when deployed to Heroku resulting in everything appearing larger in my CSS grid. As you can see by how many tabs I have open, I've tried finding the solution and still remain stuck.

See screenshots. Everything is bigger on Heroku, because the viewport is smaller (see pixel size of selected element).

First image is Heroku/production app, second is my local server. (see urls).

Any ideas? Thank you.

[image: heroku/production]

[image: localhost/localserver]

Comment: So this likely isn't really a Heroku problem. You can't make the viewport be a different size with a server, this is a clientside issue. Have you diffd your codebase? you might have an out of date file in your Git repo that's causing this. It can be extraneous to try to go through everything.